# Is there a version of Stock Fish for 32-bit operating system?

Tags: python, chess

I'm trying to use Stock Fish on my Raspberry Pi 4. I have tried using the 64-bit version (a bit radical) but it doesn't work. All I get is this error:

```
raise child_exception_type(errno_num, err_msg, err_filename)
OSError: [Errno 8] Exec format error: '/home/pi/stockfish-10- 
linux/Linux/stockfish_10_x64'
```

This is my program:

```
from stockfish import Stockfish

# you should install the stockfish engine in your operating system globally or specify path to binary file in class constructor
stockfish = Stockfish('/home/pi/stockfish-10-linux/Linux/stockfish_10_x64')

# set position by moves:
stockfish.set_position(['e2e4', 'e7e6'])

# set position by FEN:
stockfish.set_fen_position("rnbqkbnr/pppp1ppp/4p3/8/4P3/8/PPPP1PPP/RNBQKBNR w KQkq - 0 2")

print(stockfish.get_best_move()) # d2d4
print(stockfish.is_move_correct('a2a3')) # True

# get last move info:
print(stockfish.info)
# e.g. 'info depth 2 seldepth 3 multipv 1 score mate -1 nodes 11 nps 5500 tbhits 0 time 2 pv h2g1 h4g3'
```

Is there a Stock Fish for 32-bit operating systems?

Comment: You'll need a version of Stockfish for the ARM architecture, not the x86/x64 architecture you've downloaded it for. They're quite different beasts!

Comment: Do you know where I can find the 32-bit version?

Comment: A 32-bit version won't help; you'll need an ARM version to be specific. Have you googled "stockfish raspberry pi"? I find several results...

Comment: None of them actually provide the installation instructions for the Stock Fish model which will work with the above code.

Comment: So maybe compile it from scratch on your Raspberry Pi then?